# Data Persistence - Singleton Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, singleton

I have a singleton class that stores three `NSMutableArrays`. Each array stores about 4 - 5 items of a custom object I called `Program`. How can I store those beyond the current application instance?

Should I go with Core Data? I think this is too simple for Core Data. I am already using Core Data for more complex storage in my app. Is there something like `NSUserDefaults` where I will be able to store those arrays with custom objects and retrieve them easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NSUserDefaults** can't store arbitrary objects, but only instances of **NSData**, **NSString**, **NSNumber**, **NSDate**, **NSArray**, or **NSDictionary**. You can, however, convert your object into one of those - e.g. by using **NSKeyedArchiver**:

```
+ (NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)rootObject
```

(just implement the two NSCoding protocol methods in your Program class).